# CDK: How do I configure `userData` with values known only at deploy time?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I am using CDK v2, with Typescript.

I want my bastion machine to log stuff to Cloudwatch.
The specific LogGroup I want it to write to is also created via CDK (so that I can customise the retention).

How can I customise the userData script with knowledge about other AWS resources, which are also created by CDK - so I can't know their names?

My CDK stuff is being deployed via a CDK pipeline.

Here is my CDK script:

```ts
export class StoBastion extends cdk.Stack {

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps){
    super(scope, id, props);

    // actual name: DemoStage-StoBastion-StoBastionLogGroup5EEB3DE8-AdkaWy0ELoeF
    const logGroup = new LogGroup(this, "StoBastionLogGroup", {
      retention: RetentionDays.TWO_WEEKS,
    });

    let initScriptPath = 'lib/script/bastion-linux2-asg-provision.sh';
    const userDataText = readFileSync(initScriptPath, 'utf8');

    const autoScalingGroup = new AutoScalingGroup(this, 'StoAsg', {
      ...   
      userData: UserData.custom(userDataText),
    })    
    
  }
}
```

And the shell script I want to use as the `userData` for the instance:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

### cloudwatch ###
# This goes as early as possible in the script, so we can see what's going
# on from Cloudwatch ASAP.
echo " >>bastion>> installing cloudwatch package $(date)"
yum install -y awslogs

echo " >>bastion>> configuring cloudwatch - ${TF_APP_LOG_GROUP} $(date)"

## overwrite awscli.conf ##
cat > /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf <<EOL
[plugins]
cwlogs = cwlogs
[default]
region = ${TF_APP_REGION}
EOL
## end of overwrite awscli.conf ##

## overwrite awslogs.conf ##
cat > /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf <<EOL
[general]
state_file = /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state

[cloudinit]
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_group_name = ${TF_APP_LOG_GROUP}
log_stream_name = linux2-cloud-init-output-{instance_id}
initial_position = start_of_file

EOL
## of overwrite awslogs.conf ##

echo " >>bastion>> start awslogs daemon  $(date)"
systemctl start awslogsd

echo " >>bastion>> make sure awslogs starts up on boot"
systemctl enable awslogsd.service

### end cloudwatch ###
```

I want to somehow replace the variable references in the `userData` script like `${TF_APP_LOG_GROUP}` with values populated at CDK deploy time so they have the correct values.

I'm doing cloudwatch stuff at the moment, but there will be other stuff I need to do like this, so this question isn't about cloudwatch - it's about "how can I configure my userData with values known only at CDK deploy time"?

Comment: Use string formatting and simply place your variables in the user data script. It will be inserted as tokens that will be resolved during deployment.

Comment: @gshpychka - "use string formatting" - do you have an example of what the would look like, or a link to some doco that describes it?

Comment: Just insert your variable into your text the same way you would insert any text variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with conventional string formatting tools, as if the log group were a regular string:

```js
const userDataText = readFileSync(
    initScriptPath,
    'utf8'
).replaceAll(
    '${TF_APP_LOG_GROUP}',
    logGroup.logGroupName
);
```

What this will do behind the scenes is replace all occurences of `${TF_APP_LOG_GROUP}` in the text string with a token (a special string that looks something like `${TOKEN[LogGroup.Name.1234]}`), and CloudFormation will in turn replace it with the actual value during deployment.

For reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html

Comment: So easy.  I just figured it would be tricky - started googling and finding all these weird cloudformation configurations instead of just trying the obvious thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This was all incorrect. Leaving it for posterity purposes, but not valid as it was the wrong direction

> Wherever you are synthing your template - be that in a SimpleSynth
> Pipeline**s** step or in a CodeBuild if using a standard
> CodePipeline/CodeBuild, you can include context variables in the
> synth.
>
> The command `cdk deploy` can be followed with any context variables
> you want: `cdk deploy -c VariableName=value` - if your bash script is
> returning to the shell the answers, you can store them as shell
> variables and use them in the cdk deploy.
>
> you can then reference these variables within the actual stacks with
> `const bucket_name = this.node.tryGetContext('VariableName');`
>
> See [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/get_context_var.html) or [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65737579/pass-cdk-context-values-per-deployment-environment) for more information.

Comment: The question is about CloudFormation-generated strings - in this case, the name of a Log group - not user-provided deploy-time parameters.

Comment: Ooops. You are correct. I have the post entirely backwards. I was coming from the direction that the userData script was *getting* the data not using it. My fault for answering questions before being fully awake!